# Insufficient storage space & Insert SD card

Tags: external-sd, insufficient-memory

I'm using a Meizu M6 and a newly bought Sandisk Ultra Micro SD XC 64 GB.
Internal storage is about 1.67 GB free out of 16 GB. My SD card's system was FAT32; reformatted it to exFat, now the phone won't read it (still working fine with desktop). Android version is apparently based on Nougat, OS is Flyme 7.1 Global. Phone file explorer is built-in/default; desktop is Windows Explorer.

So my phone and desktop can detect my SD, but:

1. Every time I tried to create an empty, new folder on my SD, it gave me the "insufficient storage space" message, despite being empty as a clean slate.
2. Every time I tried to use the camera, it gave me the "insert SD card" message, despite being able to detect it earlier.

Yet I can create new folders and move items to my SD if I connect it to my PC with some card reader.

For the record, I have already checked the wiki tags and similar topics, as well as format, remount, cache clear, and/or reboot, but none of them worked.

The SD card worked fine in another phone (Realmi2Pro, with a custom OS). For now, we suspect it's the problem with Flyme 7 OS.

What might cause this? Any pointers?

Comment: You need to grant write access (uri tree permission) to external sd card through Android Storage Access Framework. What filesystem do you have on sd card? What Android version you are using? What file explorer did you use to create folder?

Answer (score 0):

you could try using the Windows partition manager to format the micro sd card and create a brand new partition. You could try using the tool h2testw to check if the card is damaged or authentic.

Answer (score 0):

The micro SD works after I downgraded the Flyme OS to the latest 6 series. I guess it's an OS problem after all.